# SQL LINQ RETURN PROBLEM | How to return list type as I stated, I want to return queryresultpage as a orderlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq, class

Hi guys I have a the list type is ORDERS I use it with joins then I couldn't return this as a ORDER LIST,
is there a solution ?

```
        public List<ORDERS> Search(string kadi, int pagenumber)
    {
        int totalpagecount_ = 10;

        PROMARKETEntities db = new P`enter code here`ROMARKETEntities();

        var result = (from order in db.ORDERS
                     join user in db.USERS on order.USERID equals user.ID
                     join address in db.ADDRESS on order.ADDRESSID equals address.ID
                     join city in db.CITIES on address.CITYID equals city.ID
                     join district in db.DISTRICTS on city.ID equals district.ID
                     select new
                     {
                         OrderID = order.ID,
                         OrderTotalPrice = order.TOTALPRICE,
                         OrderDate = order.DATE_,
                         Username = user.NAMESURNAME,
                         UserUsername = user.USERNAME_,
                         Address = address.ADDRESSTEXT,
                         CityandDistrict = city.CITY + " / " + district.DISTRICT

                     }).Where(x=>x.Username.Contains(kadi) || x.UserUsername.Contains(kadi)).ToList();
        searchedCount = result.Count;

        var queryresultpage = result.Skip(totalpagecount_ * (pagenumber - 1)).Take(totalpagecount_);
        return queryresultpage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are projecting an anonymous type, I think you want to project an `ORDERS`, though I don't know if ORDERS has those properties or if you need to return something other than a sequence of ORDERS.

```
...     
select new ORDERS
     {
         OrderID = order.ID,
         OrderTotalPrice = order.TOTALPRICE,
         OrderDate = order.DATE_,
         Username = user.NAMESURNAME,
...
```

And then return a `List<ORDERS>`

```
return queryresultpage.ToList();
```

Comment: while adding repeater data source like var orders = db join, its accept but on class how to return I couldn't solve