# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type:int,string,bool>>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1

This is my code:

```
        var answers = await (from a in _context.Answers
                      where a.QuestionId == quest.Id
                      select new { a.Id, a.Name, a.IsRight }).ToListAsync();

        var view = new QuestionViewModel()
        {
            Id = quest.Id,
            Name = quest.Name,
            Scores = quest.Scores,
            CategoryId = cate.Name,
            Answers = answers // Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int Id, string Name, bool IsRight>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<eWebHotelSolution.Data.Entities.Answer>'  
        };
```

Property in QuestionViewModel:

```
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Scores { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; } = new List<Answer>();
```

I just want a detailed record of the 'Questions' table. It will contain the entire list of records of the 'Answers' table that have a foreign key equal to the primary key of the 'Questions' table and retrieve only the columns I selected in 'Answers'.

Comment: use new Answer {} instead of new {} in the linq query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437600/sql-linq-return-problem-how-to-return-list-type-as-i-stated-i-want-to-return

Comment: thanks you lujcon, I tried it and got the desired results .

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new List of anonymous types named answers (check your `var answers` for specific type!) since you are projecting the query with `select new { a.Id, a.Name, a.IsRight }`. This cannot be converted into type `Answer`.

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
var answers = await _context.Answers
                      .Where(a=> a.QuestionId == quest.Id)
                      .Select( a=>  new Answer 
                      {
                       Id=a.Id, 
                       Name= a.Name, 
                       IsRight = a.IsRight 
                       }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: My choice: `var answers = await (from a in _context.Answers where a.QuestionId == quest.Id select new Answer {  Id = a.Id,  Name = a.Name,IsRight = a.IsRight }).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Yes, it will be working too. Just a different syntax.  But the most people prefer lambda since it is usually shorter. This is why I changed it.